# Logging Flyway sql with Spring Boot

Tags: logging, spring-boot, flyway

Is there a way to show `Flyway` migration steps in the console, while starting a `Spring Boot` app? Migration is working correctly. I just do not see any log about it.

I have checked [flyway properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), but there is nothing about it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you could add this in your logback.xml file

```
<logger name="org.flywaydb" level="DEBUG"/>
```

or this to only get the sql scripts :

```
<logger name="org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it leaded me to right way.
I'm set it via properties:
level.org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate=DEBUG

Comment: Yes thats right, you can also use "logging.level.org.flywaydb=debug" in application.properties

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Spring Boot Logging docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-groups) regarding log groups. You can for example log all SQL statements done by different APIs by configuring the spring logger this way:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    sql: debug
```